# Jumping from function definition tag to prototype tag

Tags: tags, ctags, filetype-c

As far as I understand Vim has a built-in support for tags (`ctags` in this case)

Now I have a common C source and C header file. The header file has `void foo(void);` and the source file has `void foo(void) { /* */ }`.

Now when I'm in the source file, I can use `:tags foo`, it will jump to the function definition in the source file. But if I use `:tnext` now, it won't jump to the function declaration in the header file.

I feel like this should be somehow possible. Is it?

Comment: (how) did you run `ctags`? Also, see `:h gD`.

Comment: I just ran `ctags -R`, that was the mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay I've done it:

It all has to do with `ctags`:
First create two files called `foo.c` and `foo.h` to test it:
In `foo.h` write down:

```
int bar(void);
```

In `foo.c` write down:

```
int bar(void) { /* */ }
```

And in the directory where those two files is, execute:

```
ctags --list-kinds
```

You get a long list of languages with there types of tags. Find C. Notice the following line:

> p  function prototypes [off]

I would call it *function declaration* but anyway. So you need to activate tags for *function prototypes* when executing `ctags`. You do that by calling:

```
ctags -R --c-kinds=+p
```

Notice that the same applies to any other languages, e.g.:

```
ctags -R --java-kinds=+l
```

Now you can open `foo.c` (`vim foo.c`) and enter `:tag bar`. It will show you the function definition. Enter `:tnext` and you will jump into `foo.h` to the declaration of `bar`.

However also notice that `ctags` doesn't care about correctness. E.g. the `bar` declaraction couldn't even apply to the definition of `bar`, as I havn't included the header file.