# Jumping to prototype or definition of a function using tags

Tags: ctags

This post is connected with the following one.

[Jumping from function definition tag to prototype tag](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8205/jumping-from-function-definition-tag-to-prototype-tag/8206#8206?newreg=415baf15088d427ca9b0015280f1f80e)

Somehow, I did what it is mentioned there. Now, when I generate my tags file using the option `--c-kinds=+p` and I do `CRTL+]` it will jump directly to the prototype function.

However, sometimes I am in lines of code where a particular function is being used and I would like to be able to decide if I want to go to the function definition or the function prototype.

For example, using `CTRL+]` goes to the definition, and using `CTRL+[` goes to the prototype. Is this easy to do?

Comment: I always use `g<C-]>` if there are multiple matches. Does that work for you? I can add it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, that's not exactly what I was looking for, but that's a trick I didn't know and it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is `g<C-]>`, which lets one choose from multiple tag matches if they exists.

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for since ever. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`:h 'tagfunc'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27tagfunc%27) (Vim 8.1.1228 and up)
 specifies a function to be used to perform tag searches. You can use [`:h taglist()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#taglist%28%29)
 to get a list of tags and filter it inside your custom tagfunc.

```
nnoremap <silent> <c-f12> :call <sid>tag("<sid>get_dec_tag", expand('<cword>'))<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <s-f12> :call <sid>tag("<sid>get_def_tag", expand('<cword>'))<cr>

" prototype tagfunc
function! s:get_dec_tag(pattern, flags, info)
  return filter(taglist(a:pattern), 'v:val.kind =~# "^p"')
endfunction

" function tagfunc
function! s:get_def_tag(pattern, flags, info)
  return filter(taglist(a:pattern), 'v:val.kind =~# "^f"')
endfunction

" setup tagfunc, exec :tjump with name, restore tagfunc
function! s:tag(tagfunc, name) abort
  try
    let oldfunc = &tagfunc
    let &tagfunc = a:tagfunc
    exec 'tjump' a:name
  catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E426:/
    echohl ErrorMsg
    echom v:exception
    echohl None
  finally
    let &tagfunc = oldfunc
  endtry
endfunction
```

Note that i use `<c-12>` and `<s-12>` in above script, not sure it's a good idea to change behavior of `<c-]>`.