# How to jump to or list a tag exclusively defined in a header?

Tags: tags, ctags, filetype-c++

I have a .h and a .cpp with declarations and definitions, and I'd like to be able to `:tselect` only the declarations, in order to see all the functions I've got that match a pattern.

some_file.h:

```
void add_x_to_y(int x, int y);
```

some_file.cpp

```
void add_x_t_y(int x, int y) { x + y; }
```

I'd like to be able to jump to the declaration, or at hide the definitions in `some_file.cpp`. Is this possible?

[Jumping to prototype or definition of a function using tags](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/jumping-to-prototype-or-definition-of-a-function-using-tags) suggests using a tagfunc, but I'm hoping there's an alternative